# Cart Tax rate Calculation Issue

Tags: magento2, cart, tax

I am using Magento 2.4.1.
I have created a tax rule of reduced 2.5 %  on a product basis.
I have added a product having a price of 1 and quantity of 10, normally tax rule should calculate 0.25 as tax but it is showing 0.24

[image]

[image]

Here is shiping Calculation Setting inside `Store > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Calculation Settings`

[image]

Comment: check your "Tax Calculation Method Based On" value on admin.

It would be TOTAL

Comment: Store > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Calculation Settings.

Comment: Make sure with following settings

Tax Calculation Method Base On = Total
Tax Calculation Based On = Shipping Address
Catalog Price = Excluding Tax
Apply Customer Tax = After Discount.

Comment: Check my updated question regarding the calculation setting, what is worng inside it?

Comment: What is your base currency, is it CHF?

Comment: Did you check with "Excluding tax" value for catalog prices and shipping prices?

Comment: yes using Switzerland CHF currency, seems like a rounding-off error while adding one quantity it is not showing accurate and for quantity, as 2 it shows accurate, right now percent tax is set to 2.5%

Comment: so your issue is related base currency right?

Comment: I am using only one currency CHF and it is the base currency also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136182/discussion-between-s-p-and-ishaq).